# Voice and Message Response in the same response

Tags: python, flask, twilio

I'm learning to use Twilio with Python and Flask. I want to be able to call some number, give the person 2 options to type and, depending on their choice, play them a voice message and send me a SMS message with their answer.

I have already written some code:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from TwilioPhoneCall import app
from twilio.twiml.voice_response import VoiceResponse, Gather
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse, Message


@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def message():
    resp = VoiceResponse()

    gather = Gather(num_digits=1, action='/gather')
    gather.say('Hello there! Do you like apples?.'+
               ' type one for yes '+
               ' type two for no.')
    resp.append(gather)

    resp.redirect('/')


    return str(resp)

@app.route('/gather', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def gather():
    resp = VoiceResponse()

    if 'Digits' in request.values:
        choice = request.values['Digits']

        if choice == '1':
            resp.say('Nice! Apples are very healthy!')
            msg = Message(to='myphonenumber').body('He likes apples!')
            resp.append(msg)

            return str(resp)

        elif choice == '2':
            resp.say('Shame on you! Apples are very healthy!')
            msg = Message(to='myphonenumber').body('He said no.')
            resp.append(msg)

            return str(resp)

        else:
            resp.say('Sorry, choose one or two.')

    resp.redirect('/')

    return str(resp)
```

Almost every thing works fine: all the voice messages and the choice options work. The problem is with the SMS messages, which are never sent.

I've also tried to add a MessagingResponse and return both that and the VoiceResponse but than I get an application error, I think it is because then I have two `<response></response>` tags, one for each the responses (Voice and Message).

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You're very close here. The only mistake that you've made is that you use [`<Message>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/message) when responding to incoming messages, and [`<Sms>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms) to send an SMS message as part of a voice call.

So, your `gather` route should use `resp.sms`, like this:

```
@app.route('/gather', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def gather():
    resp = VoiceResponse()

    if 'Digits' in request.values:
        choice = request.values['Digits']

        if choice == '1':
            resp.say('Nice! Apples are very healthy!')
            resp.sms('He likes apples!', to='myphonenumber')
            return str(resp)

        elif choice == '2':
            resp.say('Shame on you! Apples are very healthy!')
            resp.sms('He said no.', to='myphonenumber')
            return str(resp)

        else:
            resp.say('Sorry, choose one or two.')

    resp.redirect('/')

    return str(resp)
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Yes! That did the trick. Thanks Phil and congratulations on the good work in Twilio. I'm really enjoying fiddling with its many features.

Comment: Awesome! Hope your fiddling goes well. I'll be here if you have any other questions!